# WPF - switching between two way and one way bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

In my 'View' I have a TextBox bound to a ViewModel's string property.

I want to add a submit button to the View, so the underlying ViewModels string property is only updated when this is pressed.

To further complicate things, this `TextBox` is inside a `DataGrid`. I think setting the bindings `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` may be the answer but I can't see how this would work.

Any alternative solution would be to switch the ViewModels `String` with a `TextBox` - meaning I would manually populate data.

Comment: Perhaps instead of binding to the property, you can use a command to pass the TextBox's Text to the ViewModel, and then update the view models property via the command.

Comment: Thats a good solution, but I think it would only work on a 'one button per item' basis. There may be any number of rows inside the `DataGrid`, but just one button to invoke the update.

Comment: You can simply pass the selected row through the Command using the CommandParameter. Therefore no need to have one button per row. That should sort you out.

Comment: Nah.  Simplest way to handle is to clone and apply changes to the original on submit.  Plenty of other ways to accomplish this goal as well.  Not really anything free out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind button to command and pass text of textbox as parameter.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox"></TextBox>

<Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text}"/>
```

In your ViewModel:

```
    public ICommand MyCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    return new RelayCommand((textBoxText) =>
                    {
                        if (...)
                        {
                            //somelogic;
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the Button you access the row via the DataContext

```
private void ButtonRevise_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{               
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GabeLib.SearchItem srchItem = (GabeLib.SearchItem)btn.DataContext;
```

Comment: Down vote care to comment?  That is from working code.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's not a good answer. 1 - All this does is get the DataContext bound to the button. It's doesn't answer the question. 2 - `GabeLib.SearchItem` - please don't include custom classes. It seems a bit lazy and confusing to others.

Comment: @maxp I use this in production code.  The DataContext is for the Row.    Really working production code is not of value?